# Rationale for helper T cells?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology

If my understanding is correct, helper T cells have two main functions:

1. stimulating macrophages at the site of infection
2. activating B cells and helping them undergo somatic hypermutation

What advantages do Helper T cells in mediating this process, instead of macrophages and B cells activating on their own?

In particular, I could imagine:

1. macrophages always being "on duty" to swallow pathogens that do not present self-antigen.
2. B cells already require a first activation by free-floating antigen, so they could just have evolved to not require the second activation by helper T cells.

Would this have disadvantages I have not considered, or have had evolutionary problems?

Comment: @anongoodnurse good question! I think that is because that requires a more complex evolutionary path. But in the case of T cells, the immune system evolved a whole new type of cell instead and complex secondary activation mechanisms instead of what seems like a more straighforward strategy, which seems very mysterious to me.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I skimmed the link and still don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27138/ Don't skim. Read carefully. Present your findings (research into answering your own question.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse thank you. these links to more information are gems

Comment: I have edited this question by applying Occam’s razor to it, as is required in many questions here posed in terms of “why did this evolve”, which in any case generally can only be answered by subjective conjecture. By focusing on the systems in question one can answer by make objective scientific points about the mechanisms, or, if necessary, the problems in their evolution (number of events for example). But in asking this question, focus on the mechanistic question — keep other things out, allowing users to supply them in answers only if they see them as relevant.